# ¿como obtener un dato de una tabla html y pasarlo a una variable para insertarlo en la Base de datos?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

hola buenos días comunidad tengo un problema tengo una tabla html en dicha tabla hay un campo con fechas, lo que quiero es que al ir dando clic al `td`  donde este la fecha que quiero registrar, se inserte en la base de datos.

el campo es fecha próximo mtto. ahí están las fechas que quiero ir insertando dando clic al `td` o poner un botón o algo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este código con el que estoy intentando insertar el dato pero me genera errores y no inserta nada a la BD

```
$("table tbody tr").click(function() {
  //var fecha_prox_mtto = $(this).find("td:eq(6)").text();
  var fecha_prox_mtto=document.getElementsByTagName("td")[6].innerHTML;
  console.log(fecha_prox_mtto);
  //alert(fecha_prox_mtto); 
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scripts/reg_fechadelproximomtto.php",
            data: {fecha_prox_mtto:fecha_prox_mtto},
            success: function(data){
            console.log(data);              
          }
        });
    });
```

este es mi php donde quiero enviar mi variable llena con el registro previamente seleccionado:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());

$fecha_prox_mtto=$_POST['fecha_prox_mtto'];

$insert="INSERT INTO mantenimiento (fecha_proximo) VALUES ('$fecha_prox_mtto')";
mysqli_query($con,$insert) or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

estos son los errores que me genera en consola:
el primero si toma el valor de un `td` pero todos son la misma fecha no cambia conforme eligo una diferente siempre toma esa fecha y el otro es problema de relaciones puse todo en cascada pero aun asi no se corrigio el problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por lo que indica tu error, estas con un problema con la base de datos, no tiene que ver con el frontend en si, 
el error indica que se definio un foreign key, o sea una relacion, entre la tabla mantenimiento y la tabla servicio, pero no se grabo ningun dato al momento de hacer insert, por lo que tenes 2 opciones como solucion:

1) defines que tipo_servicio en la tabla mantenimiento acepta nulos y entonces dejas en nulo el dato y aunque no se defina permite grabar.

2) llenas el dato de tipo_servicio en mantenimiento con un dato que haya en la tabla de tipos_servicio.tipo_servicio

Comment: ya  solucione el problema  foreign key como me dijiste con la opción 1 que me recomendaste y en vez de usar insert use una consulta update, el detalle que me queda por resolver seria que al momento de elegir un dato de la tabla html me selecciona siempre la misma fecha por ejemplo: 2020-01-05 cuando yo elegí 2019-07-13

Comment: ya lo solucione muchas gracias